# React reload after summit so photo that summit to OCR Process in unable to precess

Tags: reactjs, ocr

After click generate react reload the page, so photo that already attach to web is unattached. So it can't process the OCR. What should I do to make it don't reload the page and start running OCR process.

some of the code

```
  <label className="fileUploaderContainer">
    Click here to upload documents
    <input
      type="file"
      id="fileUploader"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      multiple
    />
  </label>
  <div>
    {" "}
    {this.state.uploads.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <img key={index} src={value} width="100px " alt="state.uploads.map" />
      );
    })}{" "}
  </div>
  <button onClick={this.generateText} className="button">
    {" "}
    Generate{" "}
  </button>
```

Comment: There is not enough code to make some proper assumption but I can guess that this happens because you do not stop native form submission by evt.preventDefault() in your onSubmit handler.

Comment: try using `event.preventDefault()` in `generateText` method